# change job parameter value in Groovy System Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My parameterized Freestyle job got one string parameter. `MAIL_PARAM` with the default value `FREESTYLE_ERROR`.

I am able to print the value with:

```
println "MAIL_PARAM=$Mail_Param"
```

Inside an Groovy execute Script. Now I want to change the value of this parameter based on some conditions. But I am not able to change it. I tried:

```
MAIL_PARAM = 'String'
$MAIL_PARAM ='String'
${MAIL_PARAM} ='String'
def params = new StringParameterValue('MAIL_PARAM', 'String')
```

and some more, but none of them are working. I have to change it because based on some results my groovy script has, I need different Strings inside of my parameter.

After the groovy script I need to pass this parameter to the next job. This works fine. But I only get the default value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [replaceAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html#replaceAction%28hudson.model.Action%29) should do the trick (there is also addOrReplaceAction):

```
import hudson.model.ParametersAction
import hudson.model.ParameterValue
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue
def newMailParameter = new StringParameterValue('MAIL_PARAM', '...')
build.replaceAction(new ParametersAction(newMailParameter))
```

Edit : if you get error "current build does not have any parameter" then please try "build.addOrReplaceAction" in place of "build.replaceAction".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I thought this problem will kill me -.-

Comment: I could never get this working. I can create new parameters but not replace an existing one :( It keeps saying `build` isn't a recognized class.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck use `currentBuild` property instead

Comment: The original question was about a script step added with "**Execute system Groovy script**", not "**Execute Groovy script**", not "**Groovy Postbuild**", and not a **Pipeline**. If `build` is not recognized, then you're probably not running a _system_ groovy script. I believe `currentBuild` is for Pipelines.

Comment: Hugues M, is correct, @kazuar . While gaining more adoption it's best not to answer non-Pipelines-tagged questions with Pipelines solutions. I couldn't find any mention of `currentBuild` outside the context of Pipelines, so apologies if it's just buried somewhere deep.

Answer (score 3):

modify from setBuildParameters: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Modifying-a-builds-parameters-in-a-system-Groovy-script-td4636966.html

```
def addOrReplaceParamValue = { String name,String value ->
    def build = currentBuild.getRawBuild();
    def npl = new ArrayList<StringParameterValue>()
    def pv = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue(name,value);
    npl.add(pv);
    def newPa = null
    def oldPa = build.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction.class)
    if (oldPa != null) {
        build.actions.remove(oldPa)
        newPa = oldPa.createUpdated(npl)
    } else {
        newPa = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(npl)
    }
    build.actions.add(newPa);       
};  
addOrReplaceParamValue("P1","p1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more complete example if you need to modify based in the original value:

```
import hudson.model.ParametersAction
import hudson.model.ParameterValue
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue

def transformJobParameter(Closure transform) {
    build.getActions(ParametersAction).each { paramAction ->
        List<ParameterValue> overrides = []
        paramAction.each { param ->
            // Transformation takes a ParameterValue object but returns only its new value object, if any.
            def newValue = transform(param)
            if (newValue != null && newValue != param.value) {
                // Create whatever the original object type was, but with a new value.
                def newParam = param.class.newInstance([param.name, newValue, param.description] as Object[])
                overrides << newParam

                println("INFO  - Transformed ${param.name} parameter from '${param.value}' to '$newValue'.")
            }
        }

        if (!overrides.empty) {
            def mergedParamAction = paramAction.merge(new ParametersAction(overrides))
            build.replaceAction(mergedParamAction)
        }
    }
}

transformJobParameter { param ->
    if (param instanceof StringParameterValue) {
        def value = param.value.trim()

        if (param.name == 'MAIL_PARAM') {
            'String'
        } else {
            value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this is from the rare occasions I just did copy/paste and it works like a charm.